# iPhone syncs same songs over and over

Tags: iphone, itunes, macbook-pro, data-synchronization

Every time I try to sync my iPhone to the songs on my MacBook it constantly keeps re-syncing the same ones over and over. I have my songs compressed before they are synced so this ends up being a lengthy process.

The songs in question are all from one artist, the hundreds of other artists I have on there never re-sync.

iPhone 3GS 5.1.1
MacBook Pro 2009 OSX 10.6.8
iTunes 10.6.3

Comment: Does it actually complete the process every time it syncs, but then every time you sync again, it re-transfers the songs? Or does it just try and try and never succeed? I would try turning off Genius, and also you could try dumping all the problem songs into a playlist and sync that playlist vs. the artist or album.

Comment: It does complete but as I say it takes a long time to transfer those particular songs. All the other songs which re sync happen very quickly (I believe because it's just updated genius information meta data etc.)